# Postman Pass Credentials via URL not working

Tags: api, postman

I am trying to access an API with bad documentation which doesnt explain how to access it, I need to pass a username and password in order to access the data.

When I go to the URL on a browser I am prompt for a username and password in order to access the data.

To bypass this prompt I can instead pass `http://username:password@{url}.co.uk` and I can then access the site. I decided to try this using postman but I still seem to receive a `401 Unauthorized` error.

I have also tried setting a basic Authorization token and this still gives me the `401` error.

How do I access the API data via postman if I am prompted for the credentials?

Comment: Can you share the documentation?

Comment: @DannyDainton I'll try my best to find the link, I just have a local copy

Comment: @DannyDainton https://www.axis.com/api/helpdesk/cases/download?url=https://tst-file.se.axis.com/fhapi/download/01730404/1147541/axis_license_plate_verifier_api_v1_5.pdf?UserType=staff&UserID=123

Comment: I'm using the "HTTP management API" section

Comment: @DannyDainton I manged to figure it out, I found out it is using Digest Authentication which wasnt mentioned anywhere on that doc